How to get R append not working as expected to add multiple values?
I'm trying to write some code that gives me the four quarters before the most recent quarter, but I'm having some issues with the append function.
latest_period <- exports_q[nrow(exports_q),"period"] # pulls the value "2023Q3" from the last row
LFQY <- substr(latest_period, 1, 4) # Sub-string for the year "2023"
quarter <- substr(latest_period, 5, 6) # Sub-string for the quarter "Q3"
quarter_num <- as.numeric(substr(quarter,2,2)) # Gets the number and converts to numeric format

quarters_LFQ <- c(quarter_num,quarter_num-1,quarter_num-2,quarter_num-3) # counts back 4 from most recent quarter 
                                                                         # "3","2","1","0"

Ideally, here I need it to create a list by appending the year before if the quarter value is less than 1.
years_LFQ <- c()
for (i in quarters_LFQ) {
  if (i<1){
    years_LFQ <- append(LFQY,as.numeric(LFQY)-1)
  } else {
    years_LFQ <- append(LFQY,as.numeric(LFQY))
  }
}

but it's only outputting two values "2023","2022" which is causing issues with the next part.
quarters_LFQ <- lapply(quarters_LFQ, function(x) replace(x, x<1, 4-x))

latest_four_quarters <- paste0(years_LFQ,"Q",quarters_LFQ)

I understand that this probably is not the most efficient way to do this so any suggestions would be much appreciated. Unfortunately I can't use any packages to count back the quarters as they are not installed on our system.
Thanks

do you want to use append or do you want to use c?

The problem with the original code is that in your loop you were appending to LFQ and not years_LFQ, which is what you are trying to accumulate.  Changing the first argument of each append() statement to years_LFQ solves the problem.
latest_period <- "2023Q3"
LFQY <- substr(latest_period, 1, 4) # Sub-string for the year "2023"
quarter <- substr(latest_period, 5, 6) # Sub-string for the quarter "Q3"
quarter_num <- as.numeric(substr(quarter,2,2)) # Gets the number and converts to numeric format

quarters_LFQ <- c(quarter_num,quarter_num-1,quarter_num-2,quarter_num-3) # counts back 4 from most recent quarter 

years_LFQ <- c()
for (i in quarters_LFQ) {
  if (i<1){
    years_LFQ <- append(years_LFQ,as.numeric(LFQY)-1)
  } else {
    years_LFQ <- append(years_LFQ,as.numeric(LFQY))
  }
}
years_LFQ
#> [1] 2023 2023 2023 2022

Another option would be to turn the data into numeric with a function like the one below, then you could use the numeric values to make a sequence backward by .25 and use floor() to get the year part of the number.  This mimics what would happen if you were using the zoo yearqtr class of objects.
qtr_to_numeric <- function(x){
  x <- gsub("Q1", ".0", x)
  x <- gsub("Q2", ".25", x)
  x <- gsub("Q3", ".5", x)
  x <- gsub("Q4", ".75", x)
  as.numeric(x)
}
latest_period <- "2023Q3"
qtr <- qtr_to_numeric(latest_period)
floor(seq(qtr, qtr-.75, by=-.25))
#> [1] 2023 2023 2023 2022

Created on 2024-04-04 with reprex v2.0.2

Hi, I'm sure this works but I can't use the zoo package on my system

@anona I just uploaded an answer that fixes your original code.
